# How to set raw header using winHttp for user name?

Tags: c++, windows

I used to access my own small server using Qt, and I could set my raw header using Qt like this:

```
        QString concatenated = "admin:admin";
        newRequest.setRawHeader("Authorization", concatenated.toLocal8Bit());
```

But how could I do the same thing using winHttp?
How could I add the username password as admin:admin in my winHttp header?

Answer (score 1):

Use the SetRequestHeader method as defined here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384060(v=vs.85).aspx